# how to reference a parent folder from azure devops pipe?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I am getting the following error from my build:

> '$/CCC/AAA/AAASchemas' cannot be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent.
>
> ##[error]Exit code 100 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc workfold /cloak /workspace:ws_26_26 $/CCC/AAA/AAASchemas /collection:https://usap-dev.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt'.

Here's how I've configured it:

[image]

How do I correctly add this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear: You can't cloak that because you're not mapping anything in the hierarchy above it.

You're mapping `$/CCC/AAA/FromHHHMethodist/DEV`. The path `$/CCC/AAA/AAASchemas` isn't in that path. Thus, there's nothing to cloak, because **it's not going to get downloaded in the first place**. You'd only need to cloak it if you were mapping `$/`, `$/CCC`, or `$/CCC/AAA`.